# Both HttpContextBase.Session and HttpContext.Current.Session are null on IRouteConstraint MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't reach Session on my custom RootConstraint class, it'is set to null. I've searched but couldn't find a solution.

> ```
> public class AdminRootConstraint : IRouteConstraint
> {
>     public bool Match
>         (
>             HttpContextBase httpContext,
>             Route route,
>             string parameterName,
>             RouteValueDictionary values,
>             RouteDirection routeDirection
>         )
>     {
>         if ((string) values["controller"] == "Login")
>             return true;
>
>         return HttpContext.Current.Session != null && (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAuthorized"];
>     }
> }
> ```

**Edit**

Here is how the httpContext parameter looks like on immediate window. May gives an idea.

```
httpContext
{System.Web.HttpContextWrapper}
    [System.Web.HttpContextWrapper]: {System.Web.HttpContextWrapper}
    AllErrors: null
    AllowAsyncDuringSyncStages: false
    Application: {System.Web.HttpApplicationStateWrapper}
    ApplicationInstance: {ASP.global_asax}
    AsyncPreloadMode: None
    Cache: {System.Web.Caching.Cache}
    CurrentHandler: null
    CurrentNotification: ResolveRequestCache
    Error: null
    Handler: null
    IsCustomErrorEnabled: false
    IsDebuggingEnabled: true
    IsPostNotification: true
    IsWebSocketRequest: false
    IsWebSocketRequestUpgrading: false
    Items: Count = 0x00000000
    PageInstrumentation: {System.Web.Instrumentation.PageInstrumentationService}
    PreviousHandler: null
    Profile: null
    Request: {System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper}
    Response: {System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper}
    Server: {System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper}
    Session: null
    SkipAuthorization: false
    ThreadAbortOnTimeout: true
    Timestamp: {14.09.2013 16:52:53}
    Trace: {System.Web.TraceContext}
    User: {System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal}
    WebSocketNegotiatedProtocol: null
    WebSocketRequestedProtocols: null
```

**Edit 2**

I'm using `RedirectToAction` method from an action in the same area, and the `Match` method executes twice as I trace. In the firts execution, the `routeDirection` parameter is set to `System.Web.Routing.RouteDirection.UrlGeneration`, and that time the Session is not null. But when the second execution comes up, the `routeDirection` parameter is set to `System.Web.Routing.RouteDirection.IncomingRequest` and the session is null. Why?

Answer (score 2):

First time Match is called is because MVC is building URL to which it will navigate users's browser (by sending HTTP 302). This time you have session by accident simply because it exists in that moment.

Second time Match is called is when request comes to browser. This time session is not present because routing logic is executed before session is loaded. E.g. routing might render page that doesn't require session at all.

To conclude, session is not accessible in IRouteConstraint and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should have access to the session. But in an ASP.NET MVC application avoid using the `HttpContext.Current` static property. Use the `HttpContextBase` abstraction provided to you instead:

```
public class AdminRootConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match
    (
        HttpContextBase httpContext,
        Route route,
        string parameterName,
        RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection
    )
    {
        if ((string) values["controller"] == "Login")
        {
            return true;
        }

        object isAuthorized = httpContext.Session["IsAuthorized"];
        return (isAuthorized != null && (bool)isAuthorized);
    }
}
```

In this example `httpContext.Session` won't be null. What could be null is `httpContext.Session["IsAuthorized"]` which would be normal if you never set a value for this key in the session.

Comment: Is it `httpContext.Session` null or `httpContext.Session["IsAuthorized"]`? I would be greatly surprised if `httpContext.Session` is null.

Comment: Absolutely httpContext.Session is null. I couldn't understand too. I don't know if I miss a configuration or what.

Comment: I doubt you are missing a configuration. The ASP.NET Session should be available all the time. At least it won't be null inside an HttpContext. Try creating a new ASP.NET MVC project from scratch and see if you can reproduce the issue. Then post your exacts steps allowing us to reproduce the error. It never happened to me that `httpContext.Session` would be null.

Comment: I've just tried on a fresh mvc4 project but nothing changes. I've edited my question a bit. May it gives an idea.